# How can I keep the same position on my drop down menu once a user selects it on the drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down field on my form. When I select a value from the drop down it immediately resets the focus to the top of the form.

To be clearer I have a drop down menu at the top of the screen and several input fields. The user would have to scroll down to the actual drop down field in order to select it. Once they select the value the page scrolls back to the top.

How can I keep the position the user selected on the form once a user selects a value from the drop down? I've tried nearly everything and I just need some help to get this finished.

Here is ALL my code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjswhccd/)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // creates the page dynamically
  function GetSelectedItem(){
    var option = document.getElementById("locale").value;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("locale").addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var selected = event.target.options[ event.target.selectedIndex ].value 
    console.log(selected);
    window.location.hash = selected; 
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="country-select">
  <form action="" method="get">
    <select id="locale" name="locale">
      <option value="en_US" title='0'>English(US)</option>
      <option value="en_GB" title='1'>English(UK)</option>
      <option value="bg_BG" title='2'>Bulgarian</option>
      <option value="cs_CS" title='3'>Czech</option>
      <option value="da_DK" title='4'>Danish</option>
      <option value="de_DE" title='5'>German</option>
      <option value="ek_GR" title='6'>Greek</option>
      <option value="es_ES" title='7'>Spanish</option>
      <option value="et_ET" title='8'>Estonian</option>
      <option value="fi_FI" title='9'>Finnish</option>
      <option value="fr_FR" title='10'>French</option>
      <option value="hu_HU" title='11'>Hungarian</option>
      <option value="it_IT" title='12'>Italian</option>
      <option value="lt_LT" title='13'>Lithuanian</option>
      <option value="lv_LV" title='14'>Latvian</option>
      <option value="nl_NL" title='15'>Dutch</option>
      <option value="no_NO" title='16'>Norwegian</option>
      <option value="pl_PL" title='17'>Polish</option>
      <option value="pt_PT" title='18'>Portugese</option>
      <option value="ro_RO" title='19'>Romanian</option>
      <option value="sk_SK" title='20'>Slovak</option>
      <option value="sl_SL" title='21'>Slovenian</option>
      <option value="sv_SE" title='22'>Swedish</option>
    </select>
    <input value="Select" type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

I know it would have to do with specifically the javascript part of my code.

Comment: When you say "drop down menu", do you mean the *select field*?  Your question is confusing in so many ways.  There's no scrolling at all in your example, the use of the term "menu" has a completely different meaning that you're using, and in a comment, you said that it's necessary to click the "submit" button to make this happen, even though your question doesn't mention this at all.  Please edit the question (click the `edit` link above this comment) and add the relevant details to the question, so that it *can* be answered.

Comment: @michaelgaskill you're correct I don't know what terms I should use because of my programming experience. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you, I am just taking the focus away on change.

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jjswhccd/1/

```
$("select#locale").change(function() {
  $("#locale").blur();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response & your help but that didn't do anything at all.

Comment: @Giorgio did you ad the jquery cdn to your head section? `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes I did and it still didn't do anything. The issue I'm having is when I switch to a different language the link would switch but the bar goes back to the top when I want it to stay on the language. Did you try it out and it worked for you?

Comment: After hitting the submit button**

Comment: @Giorgio then I guess I do not understand what it is that you are trying to accomplish

Comment: So if you go to the Fiddle page and run the code you will see a drop down menu with a bunch of different languages. If you select the language AND hit submit, the drop-down menu will automatically go back to the top of the list instead of staying on what you selected. So what I'm trying to do is make it stay to that language after you hit submit.